# vim: in .vimrc how to set complex makeprg command?

Tags: vim, makefile, command, scons

Usually we have :

```
set makeprg=make
```

to mean we use gnu make.

(1) So how to set it to a compound command like "cmake && make".

(2) And how to set it with argument? I tried this:

```
set makeprg=scons -U
```

It's invalid syntax. If I set:

```
set makeprg="scons -U"
```

Well it doesn't do any work, seems.

Need your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `let &makeprg='str ing'` or a backslash with `set`

PS: I'd rather call cmake only when I know i need it. Hence the dedicated `:ReConfigure` command in my build-tool-wrappers plugin.